# error while enabling email option for sharepoint 2010 library

Tags: email-enabled-library

I had followed the technical article configure incoming email (SharePoint Server 2010) article from MS technet to integrate `MSexchange2010, AD, DNS and sharepoint 2010`. After doing the steps I could get incoming mail option in library, calendar and blogs etc. But when I try to enable it; I am getting application error with correlation ID error. when I tried to open the logs in notepad; I didn't much information about the correlation id error.

I am attaching the `ULS` logs for your reference. I am getting application error in the browser with this correlation ID -

```
a943a685-c50e-4c5b-8074-790cccb99c71.
```

The attachment is in `skydrive` and the link is given below.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3397CA554CC2F3D!739&authkey=!AD-crzKyjqnS_2M

kindly revert. can somebody give me tips to correct the issue

Comment: If I were you, I would download the ULS viewer and filter the list down to your correlation ID.  Posting it here in your question, actually, is of no value to anyone because the id only means something to your own farm.  You can get the ULS viewer here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer -you will want to put it on "real-time" mode.  There are a lot of logs in the log directory; the ULS viewer will read all of them as the entries arise, and you will see the correlation ID pop right up.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure which of these could be causing your problem, but here is a link that may help you:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/jks/archive/2009/03/04/how-to-deal-with-an-error-in-configuring-incoming-e-mail-settings.aspx

Comment: many thanks.. the link really helped me...The problem the solution worked for me is situation 1 - method 2. To explain a bit more; in my app server -app pool id and farm Id used for central administration was different. i had used the apppoolid for central administration. this worked like a charm.----Cheers Sathya

Comment: Glad to know it helped :) COuld you perhaps mark my answer as the correct one then?